# Mirror maker2 metric clarification

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

With regard to the [following metrics](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/mirror/README.md#monitoring-an-mm2-process) for Mirror maker I had a couple questions:

1. `record-count`(number of records replicated source -> target):

   - Is this always a growing count per topic partition showing number of messages copied from source to target?
   - How frequently are these emitted by mirror maker and can that be configured?
2. `replication-latency-ms`(time it takes records to propagate source->target):

   - How frequently are these emitted by mirror maker and can that be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> always a growing count per topic partition

Yes. Until the JVM restarts.

> How frequently are these emitted

Per record.

No, it cannot be configured. MirrorMaker is open-source, by the way, and you should be able to check this.